# Python: Setting up virtualenv and project for 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, scrapy, virtualenv

I have `python 2.7` and `3.5` on my machine , and i can switch between them according to my projects however when i try to setup `virtualenv` for a project in which i need `python 2.7` it says

`Using base prefix 'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32'`

and furthermore when i try to start a `scrapy` project in the `virtualenv` i just created it gives

New Scrapy project 'new', using template directory

```
'c:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib\\site-packages\\scrapy\\templates\\project'
```

but i want it for 2.7 how can i achieve this , any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have `python2.7`, `3.5` and `3.6` on my machine, and I created a scrapy project with 2.7 by this way:

```
virtualenv --python=python2.7 .env
source .env/bin/activate
pip install scrapy
python -m scrapy startproject aspider
```

Answer (score 2):

use the -p argument with the path to the python executable to use. For example, on linux:

```
$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/ouss/myproject/venv
```

on windows, maybe:
    $ virtualenv -p c:\Python27\python.exe c:\myproject\venv

Comment: yea , as i said i am able to set up `virtualenv` for 2.7 but for scrapy it doesn't how i am supposed to select 2.7 option, we have to do..

`scarpy startproject <nameofproject>`

Comment: Did you source the virtual environment?
In the example above:

$ source /home/ouss/myproject/venv/bin/activate

that should switch the python environment to the virtual environment you created.

I guess you already know that and already did that... but i am asking just to make sure...